# Page not rendering on local host

Tags: reactjs

Hi i am new to the coding world , my page does not render on localhost , It does not give an error message .

I just want to console log my code. How can i achieve this

I want to create a form with static and dynamic fields

Hotel Information is static and i wish to add contact fields dynamically

Fields to add dynamically on button click = Name , phone and email . this should relate to the hotel information being submitted on form submit .

I just cannot figure it why ? help appreciated z

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./Components/App";

const DynamicForms1 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <App />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<DynamicForms1 />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Below is my code for the App

App.js

```
import React, { Components } from "react";

class App extends Components {
  state = {
    hotelName: "",
    hotelCity: "",
    hotelCategory: "",
    hotelRating: "",
    contacts: [{ name: "", email: "", phone: "" }],
  };
  onChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const contacts = [...prevState.contacts];
      contacts[index] = { ...contacts[index], [name]: value };
      console.log({ contacts });
      return { contacts };
    });
  };
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("On Submit being fired");
    this.setState({
      hotelName: "",
      hotelCity: "",
      hotelCategory: "",
      hotelRating: "",
      contacts: [{ name: "", email: "", phone: "" }],
    });
  };
  addContactField = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      contacts: [...prevState.contacts, { name: "", phone: "", email: "" }],
    }));
  };
  render() {
    const { hotelName, hotelCity, hotelCategory, hotelRating, contacts } =
      this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <h2>Hotel Details</h2>
            <label>Hotel Name </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={hotelName}
              name="hotelName"
              onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, -1)}
            />
            <label>Hotel City</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={hotelCity}
              name="hotelCity"
              onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, -1)}
            />
            <label> Hotel Rating</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={hotelRating}
              name="hotelrating"
              onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, -1)}
            />
            <label>Hotel Category</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={hotelCategory}
              name="hotelCategory"
              onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, -1)}
            />
          </div>
          <br></br>

          <h2>Contact Information</h2>
          {contacts.map((contacts, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={contacts.name}
                placeholder="Name"
                name="name"
                onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, index)}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                value={contacts.email}
                placeholder="Email"
                name="email"
                onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, index)}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                value={contacts.phone}
                placeholder="Phone"
                name="phone"
                onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, index)}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
          <button onClick={this.addContactField}></button>
          <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please mention your React version? And are you using create-react-app or vite?

Comment: hi , yes i am using create react app . i hame managed to render the same now but my addContactfields function is not working

Comment: Hey Amit, it may be helpful to create a CodeSandbox and add the link to your question here. Then you could also see if it runs on CodeSandbox, even if it doesn't run locally.